# How to split gzip files and move to hadoop hdfs?

Tags: split, gzip

I have 200 of 1GB gzipped files

```
- A.1.gz
- A.2.gz
...
- A.200.gz
```

Because I am using a hadoop cluter that doesn't support "lzo" format, I am considering the following 2 options:

> 1. Decompress each file and split it by 64Mb plain text files and copy them to hdfs
> 2. gzip the plain text files above and put them to hdfs

Is there a shell command can do this job in one line?

```
- zcat *.gz | split -l 200000 - B_art 
- hadoop -fs -put B_part* /data/folder
```

If the local directory is not large enough, I have to handle the files one by one.
What is the best method handling this issue?

**I am using this script**:

```
SRC="./test"
TGT="Target/test"
mkdir $SRC/temp

for file in $SRC/*.gz
do
        fname=`basename $file`
        echo $fname
        fname2=${fname/.txt.gz/_part_}
        echo $fname2
        zcat $file | split -l 200000 $SRC/temp/$fname2
        hadoop fs -put $SRC/temp/$fname2* $TGT/
        rm $SRC/Temp/$fname2*
done
```